# Where to inject a dependent component which has already a constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, business-logic

I have a few business objects that have to be used together to get a specific outcome. Take a look at the following very simplyfied example for reference.

My question is: how do I get a reference to the agent using DI in the Station class ? I mostly prefer constructor injection, but that is not possible the Station class already has a stationCode as a required item.

Any ideas ?

***Usage:***

```
var station1 = new Station("xx");
var station2 = new Station("yy");
var route = new Route(station1, station2);

var length = route.GetLength();

public class Location
{
    public int Position {get; set;}
}

public interface IAgent
{
    Location GetLocation(string stationCode);
}

public class Station
{
    private string _stationCode;

    public Station(string stationCode)
    {
        _stationCode = stationCode;
    }

    public Location GetLocation()
    {
        // issue here: how to get a reference to the agent instance using DI
        _agent.GetLocation(_stationCode);
    }
}

public class Route
{
    private Station _station1;
    private Station _station2;

    public Route(Station station1, Station station2)
    {
        _station1 = station1;
        _station2 = station2;
    }

    public int GetLength()
    {
        var location1 = _station1.GetLocation();
        var location2 = _station2.GetLocation();

        result = location2.Position - location1.Position;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to add a second parameter in Station constructor and resolve it using DI or add a new constructor? What do you think about immediately resolve IAgent in method' Station.GetLocation?

Answer (score 1):

Your classes seem to be having an identity crisis. When using DI, you should have just 2 types of classes to deal with - [*injectables* and *newables*](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97). Your `Station` class seems like a kludge because it both provides a service (has dependencies) and has state. To make your classes DI-friendly, you should design classes that *only* provide state to classes that *only* do something with the state (services).

## Route

This class is injectable - that is, it should be wired from the DI container.

```
public interface IRoute
{
    int GetLength(Station station1, Station station2);
}

public class Route : IRoute
{
    private readonly IAgent _agent;

    public Route(IAgent agent)
    {
        if (agent == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("agent");
        _agent = agent;
    }

    public int GetLength(Station station1, Station station2)
    {
        var location1 = _agent.GetLocation(station1.StationCode);
        var location2 = _agent.GetLocation(station2.StationCode);

        result = location2.Position - location1.Position;

        return result;
    }
}
```

## Station

This class is newable - that is, you should always use the new keyword to instantiate it.

```
public class Station
{
    private string _stationCode;

    public Station(string stationCode)
    {
        _stationCode = stationCode;
    }

    public string StationCode
    {
        get { return _stationCode; }
        // Optional: provide setter here
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
var station1 = new Station("xx");
var station2 = new Station("yy");

// IRoute is injected where you need to make the calculation
var length = _route.GetLength(station1, station2);
```

Perhaps it would be better to rename `Route` to something more appropriate, since it does not provide a route, it calculates the route length.

> Frankly, if your `Station` class doesn't have any other state than a single string variable, it would probably make more sense to eliminate the class and just use strings for `station1` and `station2`. But this is mostly just a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of two types of classes to deal with, injectables and newables, is a good idea. But when newables should contain only limited business logic, you are drifting away from pure object-oriented concepts. When you write code for a complex domain model, your newable business classes contain both business logic and data. That´s also the intention of the question, I assume. The Station and Route classes are simple examples that contain much more logic and data in reality.

So I would suggest to have better separation of concerns, by separating code for storage from you business logic. I see two common solutions for this.

1. When data is loaded in memory, a separate **StationStore** class is an injectable that loads stations and stores them in the context of the business domain, eg. in a static property:

   ```
   public IEnumarable<Station> Station.Store { get; internal set; }
   ```
2. All DI code can be hidden in a business base class. It´s less disturbing to put DI dependencies there. So an agent can be resolved in the generic base class based on the template types provided.

   ```
   public class Station : BusinessClass<Station, StationAgent>
   {
       public string StationCode { get; internal set; }
       public Location Location { get; internal set; }

       public Station(string stationCode)
       {
           base.Load(stationCode, this);
       }
   }
   ```